# How to update existing desktop shortcuts?

Tags: group-policy, shortcut

I'm thinking along the line of when a word document is moved the shortcut is only updated on those systems where a shortcut to it already exists. These shortcuts exist on the user's individual desktops, start menu, etc. Not the all user profile.

Can Group Policy Preferences be used to only update existing shortcuts but not create new instances? The closest thing I can find is the 'Apply once and do not reapply' option, however I don't want to have these shortcuts created in the first place if I can avoid it.

Edit: The environment is mixed, mostly XP with some 7 desktops. Servers are 2003, 2008 and 2008 R2. AD is 2003.

What I'm trying to do is update shortcuts where they already exist. I already have the update ready to go.

I will know the name of the shortcut already. I just don't want to put shortcuts onto all my user's desktops if they don't already have one in place.

Comment: Can we get a better idea of the environment? Windows Server 2003/2008? Windows 7, Windows XP? You might be better able to do what you're asking for with a batch script. You could check for a file, if it exists replace it, if not do nothing.

Comment: I don't understand. Are you saying that you want GP to search for and update shortcuts for moved documents but only on the systems where those shortcuts already exist?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use Item Level Targeting to only target machines that the shortcut already exists on. You'd choose the "File Exists" option and provide the path to the existing shortcut.

Comment: Perfect. I knew there had to be something available along this vein. I hadn't thought about using item level targeting in this fashion.